# Make something happen after 5 minutes has passed, while other code still runs in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, timer

I am trying to make a timer, so after five minutes something happens. The catch is that while the timer is being checked constantly I need other code to be running. I have created a sample below, of how the actually code looks, the function with the timer is in class, so I did the same thing below. Here is the code:

*This code assumes all necessary headers are included*

Class.h:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void TimerFunc(int MSeconds);
};

void MyClass::TimerFunc(int MSeconds)
{
    Sleep(MSeconds); //Windows.h
    //Event code
    return;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.TimerFunc(300); //300 is 5 minutes

    //Here we do not want to wait for the five minutes to pass,
    //instead we want to continue the rest of the code and check
    //for user input as below
    std::cout << "This should print before the Event Code happens.";
}
```

The problem here is that the code waits for the five minutes to pass, and then continues. I'm not sure if threading would be a good option here, I haven't done much with it before, if anyone could help me with that, or knows a better way to go about it, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use some form of sleep instead of [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and yes, threads would be an option but it depends on how the event handling interacts with the rest of the code.

Comment: Yes, do the "event code" and "the rest of the code" have to communicate or cooperate or interact with each other?

Comment: Okay, for sure Sleep() is a better choice... honestly not sure why the above was my first thought, and the event code with set a single variable. The rest of the code will use that variable at a later point, but not right after it is set.

Comment: Then it sounds as if you need threads (and are assuming the rest of the code won't look for that variable before it's ready, which is dangerous).

Comment: A loop of `while (time(0) < EventTime) some_sleep();` might be a bit easier to read. You have a rather odd construction of `while (true) if (condition) break;` -- in general this will read better (and shorter!) if written as `while (!condition);`.

Comment: As stated above by wonce, a sleep() would be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind your Event executing in a different thread-context, you could have your Timer class spawn a thread to do the waiting and then the event-execution; or (on POSIX OS's) set up a SIGALRM signal and have the signal handler do the Event.  The downside of that is that if your event-code does anything non-trivial, you'll need to worry about race conditions with the concurrently executing main thread.

The other approach is to have your main thread check the clock every so often, and if the time-to-execute has passed, have your main thread call your Event routine at that time.  That has the advantage of automatic thread-safety, but the disadvantage is that you'll have to add that code into your thread's main event loop; you can't easily hide it away inside a class like the one in your example.

Comment: third possibility, asynchronoous events. i seem to recall some support in boost

Comment: I think threading is how I will go about it, as stated in my comment in my main post, it only needs to set one variable anyways.

Answer (score 0):

With C++11 threads, this would work like this:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    thread ti([](MyClass &m){m.TimerFunc(300); }, ref(myClass));   // create and launch thread 

    // ... code executed concurrently to threaded code

    ti.join();             // wait for the thread to end (or you'll crash !!)
}
```

Add a private member to your class:

```
     atomic<bool> run=true;   // designed to avoid race issue with concurrent access
```

Update its timer function to loop while this variable is true:

```
void MyClass::TimerFunc(int MSeconds)
{
    while (run) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(MSeconds));  // standard sleep instead of microsoft's one
        //Event code
    }
    return;
}
```

Foresee within the class a member function to stop the threaded loop:

```
void Stop() {
    run = false;
}
```

Finally update `main()` to call `myClass.Stop()` when the timer function is no longer needed (i.e. before calling `ti.join()` )

***EDIT:*** attention, nasty error to avoid: be careful to refer to  `ref(myClass)` in the thread constructor.  If you would forget this, the thread `ti` would use a reference to a copy of myClass instead of the original object.