# How to do repeated timed-callback in standard C++?

Tags: c++, timer, callback

How can I do repeated timed-callback in standard C++?

I've done this in C by using `SDL_AddTimer`, which calls a `Uint32 (*callback)(Uint32, void*)` after its first argument in milliseconds has passed, get the return value to wait for that moment and call again, and repeat this until either the return value is 0 or `SDL_RemoveTimer` was called.

I think I can wrap this using variadic templates, or even implement it with a linked list of threads, but I'd prefer a standard library solution if there is one. I was looking at `std::future` and its related classes, but I'm still not clear how they are used.

A very simple piece of code would help very much.

Comment: `std::future()` is not the right tool for timer call back: it's more for not delaying the main thread.  But you could have a look at [this standard c++ based answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26706128/3723423).

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative would be to use standard threads.

The raw idea would be something like:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> active; 

void mytimethread ()   // function that's executed in a separate thread
{
    active = true; 
    while (active) {
       do_callback();     // you coud also use a function pointer if you prefer
       std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::minutes(1));   // wait 1 minute
       }  
}
```

To activate your timer, you would then instantiate a thread:

```
thread t1 (mytimethread);  // create an launch thread 

... // do your stuff 

active = false;    // when you've finished you must tell the thread  
t1.join ();        // and wait that it returns
```

Of course,  it's just ther raw idea.  I'd suggest to wrap all this into a nice self-contained class.

You shall be aware of a small limitation of [`sleep_for()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_for/):  multi-threading management operations *may cause certain delays beyond* the requested duration. 
For most applications it will perfectly do the job, but if i'ts a risk for you, you'll be bound to system specific timers such as `signal(SIGALRM, ...)`/`alarm()` on linux or `SetWaitableTimer()` / `SetTimer()` on windows.